# WCF ServiceModelService Performance Counter Not Installed?

Tags: wcf, windows-server-2008, perfmon

I have a newly installed windows 2008 server, with .net4 and IIS installed. I want to monitor the ServiceModelService performance counter with perfmon but I cant find it in the list?

Extra info: After some googling I found that I dont have the c:\Windows\inf\ServiceModelService 3.0.0.0 folder which seems relevant? However, I think the counter I want is ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0, but maybe they are using the same folder? Anyway I have the folder on my dev machine (also running win2008), and all the WCF counters are available there.

As its a newly installed server I guess that something is not installed, but I cant figure out what? And I don't want to install any extra parts that are not required as it will be used as a production server once setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one a way to reinstall them:
Open a command window, goto c:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319 and then run

```
lodctr /M:ServiceModelPerformanceCounters.man
```

That will register the counters. Still haven't figured out why they were not installed correctly from the beginning.

Comment: Excellent! I had the same issue and your solution fixed it.